# How to kill all tmux windows at the same time using tmux command.?

Tags: shell, tmux

I created a shell script to start tmux (in Mac)
It used to work but not after upgrade OS and computer
The last command supposed to close all windows and quit.
Any help ? Thanks

```
tmux new-session \; \
  setw -g base-index 1 \; \
  setw -g pane-base-index 1 \; \
  split-window -h  -p 65 \; \
  send-keys 'vim' C-m \; \
  split-window -h -p 50 \; \
  select-pane -t 3 \; \
  split-window -v \; \
  send-keys 'guard' C-m \; \
  select-pane -t 2 \; \
  set -g mouse-select-pane on \; \
  set -g mouse-resize-pane on \; \
  bind-key Q kill-session \;
```

> tmux 3.2a
>
> MacOS Big Sur Version 11.6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in ~/.tmux.conf include this line:

```
bind-key Q kill-session
```

Now bind-key then Q will exit all